# Getting an error saying "terminate called throwing an exception"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to developing and have created an ipad app that will simulate up until the cover.  I see the cover, then when I go to swipe to the contents page I get a SIGABRT error on this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

In the output it says this:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Could anyone explain what this means and suggest possibilites for solving? 
I have searched previous queries and come up blank.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: The first line tells you that your app crashed somewhere within the app. The debugger is telling you it terminated the app because something not allowed was attempted. There is usually more information in the lines above the one you quoted. Such as unrecognized selector called. It will tell you the selector. This is often due to a stray colon (:) getting into the selector or some other typo. Look carefully at all the debugger output or even quote it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can get the actual reason from this information. So try this:
1)Run the application.
2)Do the same step where crash occurs.
3)At the debugger window(where NSlog prints.) type "thread backtrace" then press enter.
You will see the detail reason why to crash occurs. Even than you get yourself unable to resolve the issue, Post that log into your question it will be helpfull to the others. :)